# Horror movie involving a group of friends who take a boat to a desert island. A girl in the group drowns, and her ghost returns to kill the others

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I don't have much information about this movie. I saw a description of it a few years ago on another now-dead movie review site. My PC had a crash and I lost the link to it.

Group of friends go on a boat for a holiday. They reach some desert island.
Some stalker ( off-screen) breaks boat and damages life raft or something. Boat starts sinking or burning - I don't remember exactly. Everyone leaves boat to swim ashore. 1 Girl is left behind because she can't swim. She begged someone to float her ashore, but they left her to drown.

On island, drowned girl comes back as ghost and starts to kill them off one by one.
Movie from 2000-2010 May be earlier. I am sorry that is all I remember.
May be someone recognises plot. Friend recomended me this forum as last-ditch effort to find something.

Comment: I was not able to find a movie like that but I found 2 websites that might help you narrow down the search. https://www.allhorror.com/genre/slasher?_sft_subgenre=teens&sf_paged=15&sf_paged=14&sf_paged=13 You can put the type of movie and narrow it down. Doesn't have Ghost or Spirit category but it does have movies from around the world. Since your description is not that specific like what language, country, and ages of the people, or proximate year it took place or it seemed it was. I tried on female revenge category.

Comment: Or you can try this website https://horror.fandom.com/wiki/Chronological_List_of_Horror_Films Where it gives a list of all or most horror movies by years. Maybe by reading the names it can refresh your memory about the name of the movie. It did to mine as I recalled many as I read the names. I hope this helps